# Ignore HTTPS redirection for two specific URLS

Tags: mod-rewrite, https, apache2

Hi I have a loadbalancer with and SSL certificate assigned and two webservers. The loadbalancer ports HTTP traffic to port 80 and HTTPS traffic to port 81. All requests to HTTP are redirected using apache rewrite using the **HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto** header. This works fine, but now we need to ignore two particular REQUEST_URIs but I cannot seem to get this to work as expected.

The application is using a basic MVC structure and so all URIS are sent to the index.php file, but when I try to ensure the two URLs are only on HTTP, the combinations I have tried either end in the route not being found or stuck in a redirect loop.

Below is the rewrite and combinations I have tried.

```
    RewriteEngine On

    # This causes route to not be found
    #RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/uritoignore/one$ [OR]
    #RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/seconduritoignore/two$ 
    #RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]


    # Continuous redirect loop
    #RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/uritoignore/one$
    #RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/uritoignore/one [QSA,L]



    # Redirect rest of traffic to HTTPS if not already 
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
    RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]


    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In the end I realised what was staring me in the face. I simply needed to exclude the paths from the redirection, and also the index.php to stop this from being redirected when it is rewritten at the end. The final configuration was as follows:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Redirect rest of traffic to HTTPS if not already
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/uritoignore/one
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/seconduritoignore/two
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.php
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```